# How to embed JPEG images in XAML generated XPS?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, xps

I'm generating an `XPS` file on the fly using the [XpsDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.xps.packaging.xpsdocument(v=vs.110).aspx) class. In my `XAML` template I embed a `JPEG` image in an [Image](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image(v=vs.110).aspx) container. **However, the embedded images in the resulting `XPS` are always `PNG` images** - resulting in a very large files for certain types of images.

It seems the document writer interprets the rendered images as bitmaps and then saves them as `PNG`.

Here's the code that produces the `XPS`:

```
void ConvertToXps(IEnumerable<FixedDocument> fixedDocuments, Stream outputStream)
{
    var package = Package.Open(outputStream, FileMode.Create);
    var xpsDoc = new XpsDocument(package, CompressionOption.Normal);
    var xpsWriter = XpsDocument.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(xpsDoc);

    // XPS documents are built using fixed document sequences.
    var fixedDocSeq = new FixedDocumentSequence();

    // A4 = 210 x 297 mm = 8.267 x 11.692 inches = 793.632 * 1122.432 dots
    fixedDocSeq.DocumentPaginator.PageSize = new Size(793.632, 1122.432);

    foreach (var fixedDocument in fixedDocuments)
    {
        var docRef = new DocumentReference();
        docRef.BeginInit();
        docRef.SetDocument(fixedDocument);
        docRef.EndInit();
        ((IAddChild)fixedDocSeq).AddChild(docRef);
    }

    // Write out our fixed document to XPS.
    xpsWriter.Write(fixedDocSeq.DocumentPaginator);

    xpsDoc.Close();
    package.Close();
}
```

**Q:** How can I force my `XAML` rendered images to be saved as `JPEG` in the generated `XPS`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to change the way you create your XPS document.

```
var package = Package.Open(outputStream, FileMode.Create);
var xpsDoc = new XpsDocument(package, CompressionOption.Normal);
var xpsWriter = xpsDoc.AddFixedDocumentSequence();

var fixedDocSeq = xpsDoc.GetFixedDocumentSequence();

// A4 = 210 x 297 mm = 8.267 x 11.692 inches = 793.632 * 1122.432 dots
fixedDocSeq.DocumentPaginator.PageSize = new Size(793.632, 1122.432);

foreach (var fixedDocument in fixedDocuments)
{
    var docWriter = xpsWriter.AddFixedDocument();

    var pageWriter = docWriter.AddFixedPage();

    var image = pageWriter.AddImage(XpsImageType.JpegImageType);

    Stream imageStream = image.GetStream();

    //Write your image to stream

    //Write the rest of your document based on the fixedDocument object
}
```

The key here is getting the `IXpsFixedPageWriter` with the `docWriter.AddFixedPage();`. This allows you to recreate your document, adding the images where you want them to be.

Not sure you can edit the already created `FixedDocument` unfortunately.

Comment: Makes sense. Is it possible to get this `IXpsFixedPageWriter` if the `FixedDocument` is created from `XAML` and then read using `XamlReader.Parse`? Ideally, I would want a callback where the parsers asks me what to do when it encounters an image.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I don't think so. I don't think there is anything in the .Net Framework to edit an existing XPS, which is what you're trying to do. You can basically create the XPS, but once it's created it's read-only.

Comment: In that case, the `FixedPage` must indeed be created in code-behind. Unless there is some clever way to hook the XAML parser and override the internal call to `AddImage`.

Comment: An advantage of this approach is also that you'll have more flexibility in terms of the resulting document, if you need specific formatting and whatnot.

Comment: You found a smart and elegant solution!